# "Any problem whose domain is finite is always Decidable", is true or false?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

Question no:$1$

> "Any problem whose domain is finite is always Decidable"

lets take a TM,$M$ and finite domain of problem i.e. finite set of strings for eg.  {$a,abaa,bba$}, Now the problem "whether $M$ accepts these set of strings or not is decidable or not?"

What I think is, this is Undecidable problem because, if $M$ loops forever any of these string then we not determine whether turing machine accept it or not.so according to this logic above statement is false.

Question no:$2$

Does a single instance of "turing machine's halting problem" is decidable?
As I given above example, I think this is also Undecidable.

Comment: For your second question (and, by extension, your first), if the problem you intend is "Does this TM halt on this input?" then this single-instance problem is decidable. There are two deciders, one that answers "yes" and another that answers "no". We don't know which one is the right one, but that doesn't matter: a problem is decidable *if there is a decider for it* and in any case we have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so clear what is "a problem whose domain is finite". Let me assume that what is meant by this is *a finite language*. Every finite language is decidable. The Turing machine compares the input to each word in the language, accepts if it finds a match, and rejects otherwise.

This answers your first question. Your second question is a special case of the first one.

Comment: sir,If we have to decide the membership of a string for a language then your method will work.But,lets take a turing machine $M$ and a finite language $L$={a,b,aa,bb,ab,ba} then, problem if $M$ accepts $L$ is Undecidable because of looping nature of turing machine.Then How can we say that above statement is true.If I am misunderstanding something about the above statement then please correct me.

Comment: Your misunderstanding is about the meaning of the phrase *Any problem whose domain is finite is always Decidable*. It has the meaning in my answer rather than the meaning in your comment.

Comment: "A language is Decidable" does it mean that there exists a TM which can halt on any string of this language or in other words "there is a membership algorithm for this language"? what does it exactly mean.

Comment: A language is decidable if some Turing machine decides it.